# How to get openpyxl to work under Jython 2.7?

Tags: openpyxl, jython-2.7

I've tried doing a clean install of jython 2.7.  Then the following commands:

```
cd c:\jython2.7\bin
easy_install --upgrade pip
pip install openpyxl
jython


>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 8, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 34, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 45, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers, is_date_format
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .alignment import Alignment
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.descriptors import Bool, MinMax, Min, Alias, NoneSet
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import *
ImportError: No module named base
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?  I don't see this issue when using Python 2.7 and openpyxl.

Comment: Hi, I took a step forward. by installing base `jython/bin/pip install base` now I have this error `NameError: global name 'Descriptor' is not defined` from `/opt/jython/Lib/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/__init__.py` (can't paste complete error stack here)

Comment: My previous comment gives a wrong hint. openpyxl is trying to import its base.py contained in `C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors` and it can't import it because you are in a different working directory. Unfortunately I don't know how to tell a module in jython to import from its current file directory